# how to show 5 records in one page in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a program in which i am getting the records values of items which are in entered in input field let's say in input  field there is 'a' than output should be no more than 5 and values of item started from a.

```
<script>
    function main_func() {
    if (document.getElementById('search_input').value == "") {
        alert("Please Enter a charactor / word..");
    } else {
        var con = document.getElementById('first_div');
        var char = document.getElementById('search_input').value;
        var str = '';
        var ad = ['ab', 'ar', 'af', 'fa', 'af', 'at', 'aaay', 'aad', 'gd', 'nggn'];
        var len = ad.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            var str = ad[j];
            var n = str.indexOf(char);
            if (n == 0) con.innerHTML += '<font color=orange>' + str + '</font><br><br><br><br><br>';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You will need to give us more information than this to help you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please be more specific than "it doesn't work".

Comment: actually even "it doesn't work" would be nicer than an unformatted copy/paste of broken javascript with no explanation.

Comment: This question is a good illustration of what "Not a real question" means.

Answer (score 2):

Use a counter for the found matches that stops the loop when it hits the upper limit.

```
var matches = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < len && matches < 5; j++) {
    var str = ad[j];
    var n = str.indexOf(char);
    if (n == 0) {
        con.innerHTML += '<div class="result">' + str + '</div>';
        matches++;
    }
}
```

And for the love of everything holy, don't use `<font>`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RrAWs/

(There are still bugs there, this solves only the limit-to-five question.)

Comment: Thanks it is working fine but if i am going to press search button second time than records are repeated.

Comment: That's what I meant with the "there are still bugs there" part. But it should be trivial to either clear the container before showing the results or replace the innerHTML with new results.